# Setting up openVpn as an interface rather than routing all traffic from paid vpn

Tags: openvpn, interface, policy-routing, split-tunnel

I have subscribed to a VPN provider that's provides openVpn config files.

Now instead of routing all traffic through this VPN, I would like to simply set it up as another interface where the software package that have the ability to use this interface (tun0) can send and receive packets

I understand that adding

```
--pull-filter ignore redirect-gateway
```

Stops adding default tables from server side.

I'm stuck on what routes to add so that

```
curl --interface tun0 ifconfig.co
```

Gives me the VPN IP and

```
curl --interface eth0 ifconfig.co
```

Gives my standard wan ip

Assuming this will then allow programs to select which interface to use for their internet connection.

Comment: I've posted pretty much exactly the same question here https://serverfault.com/questions/992624/vpn-client-doesnt-have-internet-connection, albeit with more detail